# How to fix RTL symmetry warnings

Tags: android, android-layout

Forgive me if I ask a duplicate question, I've tried searching for it first :)

I have disabled the right-to-left support in `AndroidManifest` by putting

```
android:supportsRtl="false"
```

but I still get warnings about RTL symmetry in my layouts:
[image]

(My `targetSdkVersion` is higher than `17`)

How can I fix these warnings, other than by suppressing the warnings or adding the symmetry attribute?

Comment: why not just add the symmetry attribute ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody I don't need `paddingStart`

Comment: can't you just set it to 0 ?

Comment: I could, but that would just clutter the layout to hide warnings that should not be there in the first place. I want to fix the problem, not the symptom.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable this lint check in the `build.gradle` script:

```
android {

    //.....

    lintOptions {
        disable 'RtlHardcoded','RtlCompat', 'RtlEnabled'
    }
}
```